# "start worker process" error in datadog when i triggered CD pipeline from harness?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

Whenever I triggered CD pipeline i see printed a flurry of "start worker process" messages: in the datadog after then logs recieved

```
2024/01/25 15:21:18 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2024/01/25 15:21:18 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
2024/01/25 15:21:18 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 65535:65535
2024/01/25 15:21:18 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r10)
Jan 25 20:51:18.317 2024/01/25 15:21:18 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.3
Jan 25 20:51:18.307  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
Jan 25 20:51:18.300   /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
Jan 25 20:51:17.78    /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
Jan 25 20:51:17.776  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
Jan 25 20:51:17.776 /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
Jan 25 20:51:18.300  /docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
```

I'll show you the Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, and nginx.conf codes.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --configuration=development
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the nginx conf that we created to the container
COPY ./nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
volumes:
  angularngixvolume:
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    listen [::]:80;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    gzip                    on;
    gzip_comp_level         6;
    gzip_vary               on;
    gzip_min_length         1000;
    gzip_proxied            any;
    gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    gzip_buffers            16 8k;
    client_max_body_size    256M;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
      location /ui/health {
            access_log off;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
            return 200 "Healthy\n";
        }
}
```